# FCM обрабатывается в service, почему не в broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Вкратце понятно, что приложение регистрируется в *FCM* и потом по токену *FCM* отправляет сообщение в необходимом направлении...
Но как его обрабатывает система? По идее система должна была получить сообщение и разослать его бродкастом и уже приложение в `BroadcastReceiver` обработать его. Но тут в качестве приемника стоит **service** при чем аж ни разу не субкласс сервиса, а какой-то `FirebaseMessagingService`.
Мне интересно что за служба изначально принимает *FCM* и что она с ним делает? Как так получается, что даже после перезагрузки устройства сообщения принимаются (то есть без бродкастресивера и загруженного сервиса)?
На сколько *FCM* надежней *GCM* в плане утери сообщений?

Answer (score 3):

1) Посмотрел, `FirebaseMessagingService` наследуется от `Service`, иначе, как бы вы его в манифесте прописали?

Первый уровень `FirebaseMessagingService extends  com.google.firebase.iid.zzb`

Второй уровень `com.google.firebase.iid.zzb extends Service`

Вы можете отослать Broadcast самостоятельно:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT");
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        for (String key: data.keySet()) {
            extras.putString(key, data.get(key));
        }
        intent.putExtra("extras", extras);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

2) В результате использования FCM, жалобы от пользователей на получение PUSH уведомлений стали очень редкими, чего нельзя сказать о GCM, поэтому можно сделать вывод что она намного стабильнее, да и юзать/подключать ее намного проще.